# Countdown flickering in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, countdowntimer

I'm trying to add multiple countdowns in a RecyclerView but when I add more than one countdown with different seconds remaining, it starts flickering. How can I fix this?

That's my code:

Adapter:

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder:MyViewHolder, position:Int){
       val list = list[position]
       holder.binding.apply{
          timer = object: CountDownTimer(secondsRemaining, 1000){
             override fun onTick(millis: Long){
                val secleft = millis / 1000
                tvcountdown.text =  secleft.toString()
             }
             override fun onFinish(){
                this.start()
             }
          }
       }
    }

    class MyViewHolder(val binding: MyItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

Comment: It looks like `tvcountdown` is a property of your adapter, so you keep changing which timer is modifying it as the recycler view is scrolled. You need to put your Timer in the item class so there is a separate timer for each item, and you need to modify the TextView in the specific associated view holder. By item class, I mean whichever class you have a List of that you are displaying with this RecyclerView.

Comment: Can you provide me a sample? I think I'm not understanding you.

Comment: Can you show your item class? And when do you want the timers to start? I'm guessing you don't want them to simply start (and restart) every time they scroll into view, which is sort of what your code above would do if you make the fixes I suggested.

Comment: I don't have any item class, I just have this adapter and viewholder and my fragment. For item I only use adapter and xml file

Comment: You have a List. What kind of class is in your list? What do you get when you use `list[position]`? That's your item class. Might just be a String, but it's relevant to any kind of example I can give you.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood, my item class is a data class with five strings. It's a simple data class

Comment: And what about my other question about when the timer should start?

Comment: The timer should be created when the fragment is created.

Comment: My idea is to do something similar to Google Authenticator but without using system clock.

Answer (score 0):

Change animation may cause this. You can disable the change animation via the code snippet below.

```
(recyclerView.itemAnimator as SimpleItemAnimator).supportsChangeAnimations = false
```